# instanceof vs isInstance()

Tags: java, instanceof, isinstance

```
class A{

    public A(){
        System.out.println("in A");
    }
}

public class SampleClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();

        System.out.println(A.class.isInstance(a.getClass()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

Why is it false? Both `A.class` and `a.getClass()` should not return the same class!

And in which condition we will get true from the `isInstance()` method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `a.getClass()` returns `Class<A>`, but [you should pass in an `A`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
System.out.println(A.class.isInstance(a));
```

If you have two `Class` instances and want to check for assignment compatibility, then you need 
to use [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
System.out.println(A.class.isAssignableFrom(Object.class)); // false
System.out.println(Object.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Because what `a.getClass()` returns has type `Class<? extends A>`, not `A`.

What `A.class.isInstance` tests is whether the passed object has type `A`.